# How do I write a Django query to get distinct objects linked to another object?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have this class, which has a field for another ...

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    ...

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I woudl like to get the distinct set of Account objects, linked to certain transactions., so I treied this

```
class TransactionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_accounts_with_pending_transactions(self):
        """
        Returns acounts with pending transactions
        """
        return Transaction.objects.filter(status=Transaction.Status.PENDING).values("account").annotate(n=models.Count("pk"))
...
```

However, the above seems to return a list of dicts as opposed to objects.  Thus, I don't have access to all the fields from my Account objects.  Is there any way to write a query to get the Account objects such that they are already hydrated as actual objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a reverse relation, first edit your model:

```py
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', related_name='transactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can write this query:

```py
accounts_with_pending_transactions = Account.objects.filter(transactions__status=Transaction.Status.PENDING).distinct()
```

I would put that query in a method of the `Manager` of `Account`, because the query: "accounts with pending transactions" is naturally tied to accounts and not transactions.

Comment: Just an FYI, there’s no need to edit the models. Django’s default `related_name` is `{model}_set`. This is good practice though.

Comment: @KeoniGarner Yes you're right, thanks for the note.